How can I get an SAFEARRAY(short) output parameter from a COM server using C# dynamic types
I am using a COM server, which has two methods with the following signatures:
HRESULT setData
(
    [in] long id,
    [in] SAFEARRAY(short) *arr,
    [in] double* scalar1,
    [in] double* scalar2 
);

HRESULT getData
(
    [in] long id,
    [out] SAFEARRAY(short) *arr,
    [out] double* scalar1,
    [out] double* scalar2 
);

I want to call this function from C# using dynamic types:
    Type comType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("<progid>");
    dynamic comObject = Activator.CreateInstance(comType);

While the first method can be called without problems:
comObject.setData(new short[] { 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 }, 1.0, 2.0);

The second one
short[] arr = null;
comObject.getData(id, out arr, out double scalar1, out double scalar2);

gives the error

Could not convert argument 2 for call to getData

I also tried different variations of the theme, like Array, object, etc. But with the same error message.
So, how can I pass the output array argument correctly?

The solution is to use the same notation as for IDispatch::Invoke
short[] arr = new short[0];
comObject.getData(id, out arr, out double scalar1, out double scalar2);

